# Setting a Firebase User photoURL value to null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase user with a photoURL value set.

The Firebase docs say the [photoURL property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#photourl) has a `string | null` value.

Now I want to remove the photoURL, so I thought I could set it to `null` using the [Web v9 modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

But this does not work:

```
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { photoURL: null });
```

However this does work:

```
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { photoURL: '' });
```

If I use an empty string Firebase will convert it to `null` afterwards. But I can't directly set it to `null`.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: Got the same issue - have you found a solution already?

Comment: @Christian, I changed my approach somewhat. Have just added an answer for you.

Comment: I also get this behavior its a bug or the docs need correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now keeping a user doc in Firestore, and I keep the Firebase Auth profile in sync using a Firebase Cloud Function. Using the Cloud Function `onUpdate` trigger it will run anytime the Firestore user doc changes.

So whenever the Firestore user doc updates I have some code that automatically updates the Firebase Auth profile.

The relevant part for the `photoURL` looks like this:

```TypeScript
const dataAfterChange = change.after.data();
await admin.auth().updateUser(userId, {
  photoURL: dataAfterChange.photoUrl,
});
```

I do this for convenience, because I only have to worry about updating the Firestore user doc and everything else will automatically be kept in sync.

It also has the strange benefit that I can set `photoURL` directly to `null`.

But I'm not sure *why* this works exactly. Perhaps `admin.auth().updateUser()` inside the Cloud Function works differently than the `updateProfile()` of the Web SDK.